# I'm trying to convert a MS SQL Server Stored procedure to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-migration, mysql-error-1064

I have the following stored procedure in MSSQL

```
USE [db_DEV]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeleteInvoice]    Script Date: 11-02-2021 15:29:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteInvoice]
    @InvoiceNo AS VARCHAR(50),
    @ResultOutput BIT OUTPUT
AS

DECLARE @InvoiceId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @PayrollId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @Result AS BIT
DECLARE @TransactionTypeId AS INT
DECLARE @InvoiceStatus AS INT

BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRY
            SELECT @InvoiceId = Id, @CustomerId = CustomerId, @TransactionTypeId = TransactionTypeId, @InvoiceStatus = [Status] FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceNo=@InvoiceNo;

            /* Check if an invoice is in Open, In Review or Pending Approval status and if it's not of payment type */
            IF (@InvoiceStatus = 1 OR @InvoiceStatus = 2 OR @InvoiceStatus = 3) AND (@TransactionTypeId < 6)
                BEGIN
                    
                    BEGIN TRAN
                    
                    SELECT @PayrollId = Id FROM Payroll WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId;

                    /* Check if an invoice is a payroll */
                    IF @TransactionTypeId = 1
                        BEGIN
                            DELETE FROM PayrollItemFee WHERE PayrollItemId IN (SELECT Id from PayrollItem WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PayrollId = @PayrollId);
                            DELETE FROM PayrollItemBenefits WHERE PayrollItemId IN (SELECT Id from PayrollItem WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PayrollId = @PayrollId);
                            DELETE FROM PayrollChangeItem WHERE PayrollId = @PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM PayrollItem WHERE PayrollId = @PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM PayrollFee WHERE PayrollId = @PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM Payroll WHERE Id = @PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM Activity WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId AND [DATA] = 'New Payroll invoice added ' + @InvoiceNo
                        END
            
                    DELETE FROM TransactionHistory WHERE RecordId = @InvoiceId
                    DELETE FROM OpenTask WHERE RelatedEntityId = @InvoiceId
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceDocument WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceNote WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceRelated WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceRelated WHERE RelatedInvoiceId = @InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM Invoice WHERE Id = @InvoiceId;  

                    SET @Result=1

                    COMMIT TRAN
                END
            ELSE
                SET @Result = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            PRINT(ERROR_MESSAGE())
            SET @Result=0
        END
    END CATCH

    SELECT @Result AS ResultOutput
END
GO
```

I have tried to convert it into MySQL

```
USE db_DEV;
 

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteInvoice (
    InvoiceNo VARCHAR(50),
    OUT ResultOutput TINYINT )
BEGIN

DECLARE InvoiceId CHAR(36);
DECLARE PayrollId CHAR(36);
DECLARE CustomerId CHAR(36);
DECLARE Result TINYINT;
DECLARE TransactionTypeId INT;
DECLARE InvoiceStatus INT;

BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRY
            SELECT Id, CustomerId, TransactionTypeId, Status INTO InvoiceId, CustomerId, TransactionTypeId, InvoiceStatus FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceNo=InvoiceNo;

            IF (InvoiceStatus = 1 OR InvoiceStatus = 2 OR InvoiceStatus = 3) AND (TransactionTypeId < 6)
                THEN
                    
                    START TRANSACTION;
                    
                    SELECT Id INTO PayrollId FROM Payroll WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId;

                    IF TransactionTypeId = 1
                        THEN
                            DELETE FROM PayrollItemFee WHERE PayrollItemId IN (SELECT Id from PayrollItem WITH; (NOLOCK) WHERE PayrollId = PayrollId);
                            DELETE FROM PayrollItemBenefits WHERE PayrollItemId IN (SELECT Id from PayrollItem WITH; (NOLOCK) WHERE PayrollId = PayrollId);
                            DELETE FROM PayrollChangeItem WHERE PayrollId = PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM PayrollItem WHERE PayrollId = PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM PayrollFee WHERE PayrollId = PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM Payroll WHERE Id = PayrollId;
                            DELETE FROM Activity WHERE CustomerId = v_CustomerId AND `DATA` = CONCAT('New Payroll invoice added ' , p_InvoiceNo);
                        END IF;
            
                    DELETE FROM TransactionHistory WHERE RecordId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM OpenTask WHERE RelatedEntityId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceDocument WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceNote WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceRelated WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceRelated WHERE RelatedInvoiceId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId;
                    DELETE FROM Invoice WHERE Id = InvoiceId;   

                    SET Result=1;

                    COMMIT ;
            ELSE
                SET Result = 0;
            END IF;
    END; TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            SET Result=0;
        END IF;
    END; CATCH

    SELECT Result AS ResultOutput;
END//
//

DELIMITER ;
```

But I am getting the following error.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON  BEGIN TRY    SELECT Id, CustomerId, TransactionTypeId, Status INTO ' at line 14

I doubt the error has to do something with the usage of
`SET XACT_ABORT ON`

Also need some help in converting TRY CATCH with EXIT HANDLER

I'm relatively new to databases and I'm trying to get this done without the help of our DB team.
Can anybody guide me on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't just take a T-SQL statement and dump it into MySQL and expect it to work. The Dialects are quite different. You need to take the time to (re)write it in the dialect you are using.

Comment: Curious why you don't use cascading FKs?

Comment: Your code is just rife with errors (such as invalid hints and semicolons in the middle of statements).  Fixing it seems too broad for a single question.

Comment: Pretty sure "TRY" isn't valid in MySQL, so that's probably the specific problem. But as others have said - the two dialects are very different, and you have lots of errors in the code.